# how to replace the result from a json request into a variable

Tags: android

I would like to return in v0 the following answer "FR" instead of the country retrieved from Json

.method public getCountryCode()Ljava/lang/String;
.registers 2

```
.line 11
iget-object v0, p0, Lfr/francetv/player/webservice/model/geo/GeoInfo;->countryCode:Ljava/lang/String;

return-object v0
```

.end method

could any one help please.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `iget-object` with the opcode you'd like, then `smali` the file back up.

So for your case it would be;

```
const-string v0, "FR"

return-object v0
```